# Tkinter: Reading int with get() from the window

Tags: python, tkinter, get

I want to press any certain number into the window, then my submit output shall request the `def lotto(anzahl):` and give an output like: `4,20,40;` if I enter 3 forex What exactly do I miss that `anzahl` is still not defined?

```
import Tkinter
window = Tkinter.Tk()
lot = Tkinter.Entry(window)
lot.pack()
anzahl = int(lot.get())
def lotto(anzahl):
    for i in range(anzahl):
        result_text = random.randint(1,45)
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Result", result_text)
submit = Tkinter.Button(window, text="Submit", command=lambda:       lotto(anzahl))
submit.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `anzahl = int(lot.get())` is executed before the mainloop starts, the user hasn't had a chance to enter anything into the Entry widget at that stage.

Comment: Move `anzahl = int(lot.get())` to the first line of your function `lotto()` and remove the argument.

Comment: If this is for generating lotto numbers you don't want a loop, since that can choose numbers that have already been chosen.  BTW, that loop keeps overwriting `result_text`, so only the last value is saved. But as I said, you don't want a loop, instead you should use `random.sample`. Also, the message arg of MessageBox needs to be a string, not a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to move `anzahl = int(lot.get())` into your function if you want it to actively update with the button press. As it is now all you are doing is assigning an empty string because it only `get()` the value at the start.

Take a look at the below code:

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
import random

window = Tkinter.Tk()
lot = Tkinter.Entry(window)
lot.pack()

def lotto():
    anzahl = int(lot.get())
    for _ in range(anzahl):
        result_text = random.randint(1,45)
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Result", result_text)

submit = Tkinter.Button(window, text="Submit", command=lotto)
submit.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I suspect that the OP wants `anzahl` to determine how many random numbers are displayed in the message box. To paraphrase the question, if 3 is entered they want an output like 4, 20, 40.

Comment: o, but yes, totally forgot to write '''anzal = int(lot.get.get())''' below the function

Comment: is there a possible way to write it with def lotto(anzahl):the argument

Comment: +: // tkMessageBox.showinfo("Result", result_text) needs to be exactly below result_text = random.randint(1,45)

Comment: I only worked with what you provided. That is why the messagebox line is where it is.